# Find/Replace in Git Commit Log

Tags: git, history, privacy, git-filter-branch

How can I rewrite our commit history to ensure certain keywords never appear?

Background: we have three tiers of repositories:

1. **Local** - our development environments.
2. **Internal** - our team's private GH repository
3. **Client** - Production / end client.  All of our real names, emails, etc. must never make it here.

I've already found that `git-filter-branch` can help rewrite history to strip out names, using something like this...

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='safeusername'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='safe@email.com'; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='safeusername'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='safe@email.com';" HEAD
```

This appears to work great.  When I push to the final remote, none of our names are present.  However, upon some merges, I don't want any branch names or other comments to potentially come out on accident.

Additionally, I want our actual emails and usernames to continue to be configured so our internal project management system works and is transparent.

How can I ensure a list of keywords or names never appear in commit *messages*?  Also, any other approaches to solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yikes. Asking to interoperate between repositories where real names/emails *can't* be present and repositories where they *must* be present is... risky, to say the least.

Comment: Luckily I'm keeping them in separate directories, and combining whatever filters I can into the push script.  Also, it's one way.  I'll never be pulling in code from the client repos - ever.  Hopefully that makes it simpler (or less scary).

Comment: Only sort of: you're still moving data in the direction that possibly leaks information. Do you actually need a *repository* on the client side, with all the (possibly rewritten) commits you've made in your internal repos?

Comment: Yes - the client would like to see the changes coming in and perform their own versioning as well.  An another option may be to build a package from my repo and apply them to the client repository with its own combined commits.  I'd like to avoid that since we lose a lot of valuable history with that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the general flow you want for doing something like this is:

- clone/pull into an unmodified repo (possibly a new one every time, possibly re-use)
- run filter-branch, doing magic
- verify that everything is safe
- publish to client repos

So first: the magic. You'll want to use `git filter-branch --commit-filter my-commit-filter-script`. It's called directly instead of commit-tree, taking necessary arguments, and the commit message on stdin. So you'll want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(sanitize "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
# ... similar for AUTHOR_EMAIL, COMMITTER_(NAME|EMAIL)

sed 's/scary-string/safe-string/' |
git commit-tree "$@"
```

That is, change the names and emails via the appropriate environment variables, run whatever filtering you need on the message, and pipe it along to the commit-tree invocation that'd have been run normally. `sanitize` is meant to be a function/script that does some private->public mapping of names/emails; if all you want to do is change them all to a single name, then that bit is really easy. And the `sed` command presumably might be something a little fancier, which for example reads a table of transformations. That bit is up to you, depending on the complexity of the sanitization you need to do.

If you trust your commit message filtering, then you're done at this point. If you want to validate, you can do it manually, or you can independently search for the "dangerous" strings. For example, if you have a file `dangerous-strings.txt`, you could do `git log --pretty="%an %ae %cn %ce%n%B" [branches] | grep -f dangerous-strings.txt`. (The log command prints author/committer name/email followed by the commit message.)

Then publish as normal - push, presumably.

Finally, a few alternate suggestions, perhaps for future readers with different requirements:

- Instead of rewriting commits, make new commits. The message could just be quick versioning information (including the SHA1 of the internal commit it represents), or it could include a shortlog of the commits being introduced (just the subjects). You could do this by keeping a publishing branch and using `git merge --squash [--log]`, or by committing fresh in a separate repo, after copying things in.
- Keep your repo in a form that doesn't need the transformation. This seems to be impossible for the OP, but if your situation is different, keep it simple. Less risky, less work.

Comment: Not quite working for me - here is what I'm using / what it outputs: https://gist.github.com/2127452

If I can't get it working right this way, I may go with your alternate suggestion and export it and then dump it into a new repository.  Out of curiosity and learning I definitely want to give this a go first though.

FYI - by "pre-push", I mean I'm running it manually, not as a git hook.

Comment: Hm, I have to admit I didn't test it, and I may not have time to do so today. In the meantime, since it did print a usage statement, I'd suggest logging stdin, what you're piping to commit-tree, and the arguments, and seeing if anything is obviously wrong.